# What does 'mount point' mean in a Linux installer?

Tags: mount, system-installation, backup, home

While installing Linux, it asks for a 'mount point' selection. I gave it `/`, but I don't know the exact meaning and aim of this.

Also, now I want to create one more mount point, `/home` in my machine with the already installed Linux with mount point `/`. Is it possible to do that from my current Linux install? If yes, what are the steps/commands?

My understanding of 'mount point' is, when I need to preserve my `/home` contents in a safer way that it won't get deleted if my current Linux get corrupted. For example, by detaching and connecting the hard disk from the machine with corrupted Linux to a new Linux machine, I should get my `/home` content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mount point specifies at which location in the directory hierarchy a device or disk partition appears.

If you want to move `/home` to a new partition, you have to create a new partition for it, say `/dev/sda4` and format it, e.g. with ext4. Creating partitions and formatting them can be comfortably done using e.g. [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Then you have to copy the old contents to the new partition and modify `/etc/fstab` so `/home` points to the new partition. As root do something like this after having the partition created and formatted. Again, I assume `/dev/sda4` for the partition, this is just an example and you have to use your real partition device:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/tmphome
$ mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/tmphome
$ cd /home/
$ find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null --sparse -pvd /mnt/tmphome/
$ umount /mnt/newhome
$ mv /home /old_home
$ mkdir /home
$ mount /dev/sda4 /home
```

Now check if your system is still working correctly. If it does, add a line like this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda4 /home ext4    defaults        1 2
```

and delete the backup in `/old_home`

if however you find that something went wrong, you can move back by not adding respectively removing the above line in `/etc/fstab` and doing as root

```
$ umount /home
$ rmdir /home
$ mv /old_home /home
```

This answer is inspired by the howto on http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/

Comment: Then you are telling that, if i connect my hard disk to another Linux machine, i will get all my ' /home ' contents in /dev/sda4 partition ?

Comment: /dev/sda4 is just an example. It's not clear to me, what you mean with "if i connect my hard disk to another Linux machine, i will get all my ' /home ' in /dev/sda4"

Comment: Yes. I got your point about /dev/sda4. Suppose my machine got corrupted(lets say the LINUX itself). I want to get all the data from that machine. The data is in the hard disk right? I have kept all the data in my '/home/renjithg' directory. On corruption of the LINUX in my machine probably would cause its home to corrupt right? So i will not get that data under /home on connecting the hard disk to another machine right? To avoid that , If i have mounted that '/home' earlier then then i would get that data under /home if i connect my hard disk to another Linux machine?

Comment: A broken Linux distribution should not destroy your data. This is very, very unlikely. In 99% of all cases, you can boot a Live-CD, mount your partitions and you data is accessible, even if your installation is broken and e.g. doesn't boot anymore. Whether /home is on the same partition as / is not really relevant for this.

Comment: What happens if my machine is not having a CD ROM?

Comment: Then you obviously can't boot a Live-CD. Take a Live-USB-Stick or put your hard disk into an USB- or ESATA-enclosure, or buy a USB-DVD-Drive or put your hard disk into an other machine. Possibilities are endless.

Comment: yes, am preferring the last option " put your hard disk into an other machine" . Now you got my question. we can start from here. If connect my hard disk to another linux machine , how can i get my datas under "/home/renjithg" , for that i have to create a mount point for '/home' earlier in my first linux  machine

Comment: On the new machine, find out which id the partition has (this may or may not be the same as on the old one), e.g. /dev/sdb4 and mount it like described in my original answer. How to find out is a different question. I seem to remember it has been asked here before.