# Disk renamed automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, docker, disk

One month ago I bought a new SSD disk for my PC, that I connected with the SATA3 port to my motherboard. I created a partition `/dev/sda3` on that disk and I named it PatriotSata3.

It was working correctly through all month. I had to mount it manually before using it and then it was visible in `/media/username/PatriotSata3`.

Yesterday I moved all the Docker data to this PatriotSata3 disk with [this tutorial](https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/) as I ran out of space on my main disk.

Today when I logged on, I saw that the path `/media/username/PatriotSata3` is visible before my manual mounting but is empty and I get

```
ls: Cannot open directory '.': Access denied
```

When I try to list the directory.
But then when I mount the disk manually it's visible under the path `/media/username/PatriotSata31` and has all the files. The `/media/username/PatriotSata3` is also visible but the access is still denied.

How can I go back to the previous state with all the files seen under `/media/username/PatriotSata3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk wasn't renamed, it is only mounted in a different location/[mountpoint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/what-does-mount-point-mean-in-a-linux-installer), it doesn't really makes a difference. From the `/media/<username>/<label>` mountpoint, I'm guessing you are either mounting from GUI (e.g. from Nautilus application) or from terminal using `udisksctl` so the mounting a mountpoint selection is done by UDisks. Older versions of UDisks have a bug where the mountpoint is not automatically removed after unmounting the drive and next time the existing directory is not reused, but rather a new mountpoint with `1` added to it is used. You can simply remove the old directory (but please on't remove the one being currently used) a next time, it will be created again.

If you plan to use the new disk more often and don't want to mount it manually everytime, I'll recommend adding it [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to have it automatically mounted after every boot (and you can also choose better mountpoint that won't change).

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue.

Comment: Great, you can [mark the answer as solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: I have one more quick question. If I want to use fstab and the result of `sudo blkid` is `/dev/sda3: LABEL="PatriotSata3" UUID="18377429-10a0-433b-b2ce-9eb2929cf1ab" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="PatriotSATA3" PARTUUID="d5da4455-f5ce-47fd-932e-0f58c8eccce9"` then new line in fstab should look like this: `/dev/sda3 /media/username/PatriotSata3 ext4 defaults 0 2` ?

Comment: You can use `UUID=18377429-10a0-433b-b2ce-9eb2929cf1ab` instead of `/dev/sda3` but both should work.